# How to write Hibernate Criteria to get records only between two date and month not year

Tags: hibernate, date, criteria

I am creating an application, I am letting user to  enter their date of Birth(dd/mm/yyyy).

What I need is to get the records dependent on month and day not year.

Ex:

1. 01/01/1993
2. 08/01/1995
3. 30/01/2015

If user searches for the next date of birth between two dates

- from Date 01/01/1993
- to Date 01/10/1999

I need to display first two records.

Can anybody help.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268233/how-to-use-datepart-in-an-nhibernate-criteria-query

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: Its for Nhiberante. Can I use it for hibernate.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger:I using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Comment: I ... guess it is the same. The sql function in hibernate should be quite similar. The syntax in SQL however depends on your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use DATE_FORMAT, and SqlRestriction.

```
String sqlWhere = " DATE_FORMAT( " + "{alias}.date_of_birth"+ ",'%m-%d') BETWEEN '" + 
String.format("%02d", fromMonth) + "-" + 
String.format("%02d", fromDate)  +  "' and  '" + 
String.format("%02d", endMonth) + "-" +
String.format("%02d",  endDate )+ "'" ;
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(sqlWhere )  );
```